# can't get custom Dimension Value Google Analytics Android

Tags: android, google-analytics

I'm using this code for setting custom dimension

```
tracker.send(new HitBuilders.ScreenViewBuilder()
  .set("&cd", "Home Screen")
  .build()
);
```

also tried this :

```
 mTracker.send(new HitBuilders.ScreenViewBuilder()
                        .set("&cd1", "premiumUser")
                        .build()
        );
```

and for getting value :

```
 mTracker.get("&cd1");
```

but nothing work ,I have no idea how to get the current set value for this dimension.
I used alot of resources but nothing works. Also I followed all steps for setting custom dimensions in my Account.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Your code sets the custom dimension to a single hit and then reads from the tracker object. That's the reason reads don't work.

Assuming you want to add the "premiumUser" custom dimension to all subsequent hits, and its dimension index is 1, your code should be as follows:

```
mTracker.set("&cd1", "premiumUser");
```

Then you should be able to read it from tracker object:

```
mTracker.get("&cd1");
```

You can find documentation for Tracker [here](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/analytics/Tracker).

As a side comment, if you need to set a custom dimension for a single hit, there is a different method in HitBuilder which is recommended for this purpose:

```
mTracker.send(new HitBuilders.ScreenViewBuilder()
                    .setCustomDimension(1, "premiumUser")
                    .build()
    );
```